# SOCKS5 Proxy Authentication in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, proxy, socks

I'm trying to create a extension which would use my SOCKS5 proxy with authentication.
Code in my background script is like this:

```
var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
        fallbackProxy: {
            scheme: "socks5",
            host: "myhostaddress"
        }
    }
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set(
    { value: config, scope: 'regular' },
    function () { });

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    function (details) {
        console.log("onAuthRequired!", details);
        return ({
            authCredentials: {
                'username': "uname",
                'password': "pass"
            }
        });
    },
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
    ['blocking']
);
```

But I always get `ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED` error on each page...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [thread](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/4222/socks5-proxy-can-not-connect), Chrome doesn't support SOCKS5 proxy with authentication. The only browser that might be supported is [Maxthon browser](http://www.maxthon.com/).

Comment: any signs of future implementation inside Chrome?

Comment: Just founded [Firefox 57+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/proxy#Communicating_with_PAC_files) supported PAC returns object array to support socks5 username/password auth.  I'm also looking for chrome's SOCKS5 proxy auth.

Comment: @btpka thats awesome but has anyone already built this into an extension?

Answer (score 1):

I write a socks5pipe gadget, it can bind local address without authentication, and pipe connections to the remote socks5 server.

https://gist.github.com/hzshang/4ebeecc442f4def42f233c6cd97c9c64

Then set your local address as chrome socks5 proxy.