# How does VPN extensions authenticate users?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy

it seems like we can't use proxy connections that needs an authentication with chrome.proxy API.

Reference: [SOCKS5 Proxy Authentication in Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928002/socks5-proxy-authentication-in-google-chrome-extension)

**I'm willing to connect to a SOCKS5 Proxy using chrome.proxy API & MV3.**

I'm thinking of authenticating the user through an API, and receiving the proxy server details once the authentication is complete. But it'll be seen in the response if a user checks the network tab.

So if someone get the proxy server address and the port, he'll be able to connect to the server without the extension because the proxy server shouldn't have authentication because of the reason I've mentioned above.

How can I prevent this?
How do those VPN extensions on the WebStore do this?

All the comments and the answers are appreciated.